# Is WSO2 Identity Server working with JSON XACML request/response?

Tags: json, wso2, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I´m new in the world of WSO2 Identity Server. Does anyone know if Identity Server is able to send and receive XACML requests and responses using the new JSON defined in the [Oasis XACML Definition](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/xacml-json-http/v1.0/xacml-json-http-v1.0.html)?

I cannot find any reference or tutorial talking about that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is supported from IS 5.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not. The only implementation to date of the JSON profile of XACML is the Axiomatics Policy Server v.6.0 ([demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqdDPJeNeUU) | [request download](http://www.axiomatics.com/solutions/products.html)).

As you probably know, the latest version of the profile can be found [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/xacml-json-http/v1.0/xacml-json-http-v1.0.html). I've also written quite a bit on the profile both on the [Axiomatics Developers Blog](http://developers.axiomatics.com) and my [personal blog](http://www.webfarmr.eu).

Comment: Thank you David. I will check out the Axiomatics Policy Server then. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Have you had a chance to try out APS?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the upcoming version 5.3 of the WSO2 Identity Server will support JSON for XACML requests/responses.

Here is the JIRA issue that has already been resolved for version 5.3.0-M5:
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-4985

Comment: Yes this is implemented in WSO2 IS 5.3.0 and its released now

Comment: Documented here in WSO2 docs - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Entitlement+with+APIs

Comment: Had to follow to next page (see Pushpalanka's comment): https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Entitlement+with+REST+APIs